# How to hide a face?

Tags: faces, customize, elfeed

I am new to Emacs (28.2) and would like to customize certain packages by simply hiding some of their elements or faces.

For example, I'm trying to remove `elfeed-search-last-update-face` from `elfeed-summary`. Alas, `customize-face` does not seem to offer any hiding option.

Editing `elfeed-search.el` works, but all changes are lost when the package gets updated.

If possible at all, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `M-x customize-face elfeed-search-last-update-face`, and remove (uncheck) all attributes.

Comment: This adds `'(elfeed-search-last-update-face ((t nil)))` to my `init.el`, but it doesn't seem to change anything: the element is still displayed the same as before.

Comment: Are you sure the thing you don't want to see highlighted has face `elfeed-search-last-update-face`? If that face is used then you should be able to see the difference immediately, just by setting, not even saving, in Customize.

Comment: Almost sure? I can't find any similar face that could be used instead. Even after restarting Emacs, I can't see a difference with or without `'(elfeed-search-last-update-face ((t nil)))`?

Comment: Finally understood! Instead of trying to hide the undesired element by customizing its face, I copied its function in my `init.el` and removed `(insert (elfeed-search--header) "\n\n")` from the `defun`. I had no idea this was possible, Emacs keeps getting more awesome as I learn! Thank you @Drew to help me see things more clearly. :)